# Oneness of God tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I think that perhaps there should be a tag for questions discussing the singularity of God. What would be a good name for such a tag?

Comment: What questions do you propose to tag with it?

Comment: @DoubleAA, now that you mention it, I actually assumed there would be a lot more questions on this topic than there seem to be. Perhaps [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15780/is-it-true-that-there-was-a-time-when-jews-believed-in-the-existence-of-several/) or the [one I just asked](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27969/is-unitarianism-considered-to-be-idolatry) about Unitarianism, although two questions wouldn't really be enough to warrant a new tag.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Daniel, also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11139.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there should be such a tag (no litotes intended), but, if so, I think [oneness-of-god](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneness-of-god) would be a good name.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83